# why my jquery won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a problem with my query code. I'm creating a simple slider and when I was creating the `#prev` button function it didn't work but it worked with my `#next` button, why is this? When I remove the `#prev` handler it works normally only with `#next`. Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set options 
    var speed = 500;
    var autoswitch = true;
    var autoswitch_speed = 4000;

    $('.slide').first().addClass('active'); // add the initial active class
    $('.slide').hide(); // hide all slides 
    $('.active').show(); // show first slide

    // when the next/prev button clicked
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        };

        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);

        $('#prev').on('click', function () {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
            if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
                $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
            } else {
                $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
            };

            $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
            $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
            $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're missing some closing braces - hopefully the locations should be easier to spot now I've indented your code. Is this just a typo in the question?

Comment: You are declaring your `$('#prev').on('click'..` inside of your next button functionality.

Comment: Yes declare your #prev outside of #next click sclpe

Comment: I did it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted the .prev button click event on .next button click event

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set options 
    var speed = 500;
    var autoswitch = true;
    var autoswitch_speed = 4000;

    // add the initial active class
    $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

    // hide all slides 
    $('.slide').hide();

    // show first slide
    $('.active').show();

    // when the next/prev button clicked
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        };

        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    });

  $('#prev').on('click', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
      $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    };

    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
  });
```

Comment: Cool, @JasonDjojo please make it as a correct answer :)